# Is it correct architecture for adding user's posts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Create action in posts controller:

```
  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
    if @post.not_exists?(current_user)
      if @post.save
        #flash
        redirect_to root_path
      else
        #flash[:error]
        redirect_to root_path
      end
    else
      #flash[:error]
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
```

Post model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  ##validations


  def not_exists?(user)
    return true unless user.posts.find_by(name: self.name)
  end

end
```

My question: is it correct to build my create action like this? Or there is a better architectural design? I think it is too fat action.

Comment: I think this post would be better suited for a [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a validation instead ?

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  validates_uniqueness_of :name, :scope => :user_id
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's what i was looking for.